# How do I browse logs in /var/log in Console.app on Catalina?

Tags: catalina, logs, console

Up to and including Mojave, `/var/log` was listed in the sidebar of Console.app, allowing me to browse subfolders and, for instance, look at `/var/log/powermanagement` logs for previous days.

But in Catalina, there are no directories listed in the Console sidebar.  Is there some way to browse these folders using Console in Catalina?

(I tried adding them by finding the folders in Finder and then dragging them to the sidebar like one would with the Finder sidebar, but to no avail.)

Comment: Have you tried opening the file with File>Open...? When the Open dialog appears, press Shift-Command-G, type `/var/log` and select `powermanagement`.

Answer (score 1):

In Catalina the interface for Console got a revamp, in my opinion not for the better.

If you click on "Log Reports" in the left hand bar you will get a list of the logs in `/var/log`. (You may have to click on the icon that toggles the bar's visibility first.) Click on a file and the log can be seen at the bottom of the window.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any of the subfolders of `/var/log` (or their contents) listed here.